# Probability based on proportions from paired samples

Tags: probability, distributions, proportion, paired-data

Consider a dataset of partial pressure of oxygen (po2, in kPa) measured in paired arterial and venous blood samples from a population (n = 38251).
The distributions of both type of blood are displayed below.

Now consider the blood of a subject X whose type (arterial or venous) is unknown, and for which the po2 is measured at 2 kPa.

**Question**: knowing the proportions of arterial and venous po2 <2 kPa of respectively 31.56% and 1.53% in the population, is it right to say that there is 20.6 (=31.56%/1.53%) times more chance that the blood of subject X is of arterial origin than of venous origin?

Thanks for your comments.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be the case if all you knew was that the pO2 was *less than* 2 kPa. But you know more than that: you know that the pO2 was precisely 2 kPa, at least within measurement error.

One caution: the displayed values for "arterial" blood are very low, lower than those for "venous" blood. That originally confused the physiologist in me, who expects higher arterial than venous pO2. Normal arterial pO2 values are on the order of 10-13 kPa (75 - 97.5 mm Hg, in units typically used in the US) for people living near sea level. Even at the [highest terrestrial altitudes](http://www.high-altitude-medicine.com/SaO2-table.html), normal arterial pO2 doesn't fall as low as 2 kPa (15 mm Hg). The OP says in a comment that the "arterial" samples are really from umbilical cord blood, so I'll call them "cord blood" below despite the label on the plot.

Look at the samples in the dataset that showed a pO2 of 2 kPa. It looks like about 4100 were cord blood and 500 were venous blood, or 4600 total. Of those 4600 samples with values of 2 kPa, 89% were cord and 11% were venous.

That would be odds of about 8/1 that the new sample is cord blood, other things being equal. That estimate, however, depends on the new blood sample being drawn from *a member of the same population* that provided these histograms.

Comment: Thanks EdM! You're right (expect that "It looks like about 4100 were arterial blood and 500 were venous blood" and not the other way around). Thus, given your example, we can claim that there is 8.09 (=89%/11%) more chance that the blood of subject X is arterial than venous, right? Is a two-proportions z-test (e.g. prop.test R function) statistically appropriate to objectify such a case? A very clever comment about pO2 levels; in fact, these pO2 values were supposed to be from umbilical cord blood, I just wanted to simplify the example...